# Spatial Voting Matrix in Canny Edge detection

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

We are developing a system to extract road network from a satellite image. One of the technique we read is to use the canny edge detector to extract the edges and the gradient information(the magnitude and direction of each pixel) and then use this gradient information derive a spatial voting matrix out of it . This matrix will then be used to detect the road networks. 
But we are not quite getting what this voting matrix is exactly. Any help regarding this would be appreciated . What is it and how do you derive this matrix and then use it ? Or suggestions on alternative methods would be helpful.

The project is based on C language entirely . We might use OpenCV if needed. 
Thank you.

Comment: This voting matrix indicates the possible locations of the road network pixels. By processing this voting matrix in an iterative
manner, we detect initial road pixels. check this link https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CFAQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.187.389%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=5_sbUb7GCMWm4gTuqoGgAQ&usg=AFQjCNFKB-6J4KCJvqYdJP2hpjQP1cYVpQ&bvm=bv.42261806,d.Yms